# Can I use a more recent GHC with the current Haskell Platform?

Tags: haskell, ghc

I have the latest Haskell Platform (2012.2.0.0) 64bit OSX. But.. I have run into an [issue with the 64bit compiler on Mac](http://hackage.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/7040), which means that `yesod devel` crashes as soon as it starts.

I can't swap to the 32 bit version because of completely different issues with getting GTK+ to work.

I see the issue with GHC is fixed in 7.6.1 but the latest HP comes with 7.4. So, can I install GHC 7.6 on top of my working HP installation, or is that going to screw everything up?

Comment: Depends on what you mean with "on top". If you mean "can I install 7.6.1 and use the installed libraries of the HP with it?", the answer is no, the compiler can only use libraries compiled with the same version. If you mean "can I have both, 7.4 and 7.6.1 installed in parallelß", you can, see pyCthon's answer.

Comment: @DanielFischer Um.. can I have 7.6.1 be the default version, so that cabal would use it? I am having trouble installing `cabal-dev` on win8, and I think it's because of the old version of cabal included in the platform, which in turn depends on ghc...

Comment: `cabal` uses the first `ghc` (unversioned) it finds in the `PATH`. Just have `ghc`, `ghci`, `ghc-pkg` etc. link to 7.6.1 in `~/bin` [assuming `~/bin` is where the platform `ghc` is installed or before that].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes just install it in a separate directory and remember to change your path each time you wanna use it with the different versions, or change the name of the simulink in your bin like how mac ports does i.e. for instance in my bin i have `ghc` , `ghc-7.4.1` and `ghc-7.4.2` which are all different versions.

so in your case i would create two simulinks in /bin  `ghc-32` and `ghc-64` for each of the two separate versions

Also it is important not to forget to CHANGE YOUR INSTALL PREFIX each build, usually denoted by `--prefix` when compiling GHC